# Fundamental C++ aspects to consider moving from java

Tags: java, c++

I want to learn C++, I already program in Java.
What are the aspects of C++ for which Java programmer should keep an eye on.

(I moving from java to C++ for game programming.)

Comment: Here's one that Java programmers seem to have trouble with: Things are values (by default and most of the time in practice). Heap-allocated reference types are the exception.

Comment: This is simply completely different language (despite similar syntax). Start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

The major thing you're going to have to watch out for is memory management. Learnt about it in C++ but do your best to use classes like `shared_ptr` wherever possible.

Comment: +1 to that, OP must remember to **free all the dynamic memory they use** when programming in C++, it asks for further responsability to programmer than managed environments as Java or C#.  Always remember every `new` in C++ means asking the OS for a resource and must be followed by a `delete` when the resource is not necessary, you are no more in a managed sandbox

Comment: I'm not sure suggesting `shared_ptr` without further explanations is such a good idea, unless you want to make C++ behave more like a garbage collected language, in which case, you might as well program in one.

Comment: @Jorge_B The strategy is to code such that you don't have to remember to free dynamically allocated memory (or other resources). C++ makes this very easy. If you find yourself doing it manually, you are making life hard for yourself, and probably writing code that is not exception safe.

Comment: Of course I don't want to hurt myself, but I must be conscious that memory allocation issues exist to even think of using smart pointers and similar artifacts or C++ idioms that avoid dynamic memory allocation.  It means an important difference compared to managed environments where OP has been living till now and they should be noticed about.

Comment: @Jorge_B Sure, what I am trying to say is that the "make sure to collect your garbage because it won't be done for you" approach, which is common in beginners and people who program in C and didn't get to learn C++, is inferior to "don't produce garbage in the first place, because the language gives you tools to do that". So new-comers should learn the latter approach and save themselves a lot of trouble.

Comment: Well, I must recognize I am not familiar to that idea (working in C++ while trying not to allocate dynamic memory).  Could you elaborate or link to some resource about it?  Is it a particular C++ idiom?